# Master detail grid in Silverlight 4 - no headers for Detail grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, master-detail

I'm developing a Silverlight application where I want the master and its detail grid to share the same columns. Some of the common fields would be displayed in master grid and rest of the fields would be specific for each child/detail.

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is difficult, why not define the same names in both grids?  Am I missing something?

Comment: but would that show the column headers as common? I mean i want only master grid to have column headers and child should use the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `HeadersVisibility = false` in detail grid.

Answer (score 0):

Is [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) - [DataGrid](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: yes. I want to disaply common headers for both mater and detail datagrid.

Comment: Than download and use Silverlight toolkit, it is free, and cool Silverlight library

Comment: I'm using that only. But I want to add the Detail datagrid which shares the Column names with Master. i.e. Master and Child would have same column names.